# node-gyp 5 on Windows: Cannot find npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js

Tags: node.js, npm, build, node-modules, node-gyp

Running npm 6.11.3, node-gyp 5.0.3, VS2019 on Windows 10 v1903, getting this error:

`Cannot find module %AppData%\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js` (where `%AppData%` is expanded to the actual user-specific path).

The error only happens if the build is invoked via npm, i.e.:

```
npm run build
```

The `package.json` file `scripts` section:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "node-gyp build",
}
```

If `node-gyp build` is invoked manually outside npm context, the error is gone.

How do I get rid of the error and still use `npm` scripts for making builds?

Comment: are you using nvm? because if you change the node version with nvm, it moves all the node directories in some his lair, so you have to reinstall all the -g installed npm modules that you need

Comment: @asdru, nope were not using nvm. See my own answer about what caused it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

After upgrading to node-gyp 5 on a Windows 10 build system, I started getting the infamous `Error: Cannot find module ... npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js`, caused by `node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin` being pushed on top of my `PATH` by npm, exactly as described [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1760).

None of the existing remedies I've found and tried could solve this issue for me, including installing the latest [`windows-build-tools`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/pull/188). Here's exactly what I tried, in the following order:

- manually clean up the mess and duplicates in System `PATH` and User `PATH` environment vars
- reboot
- `choco unistall nodejs`
- `rd /s %AppData%\npm\`
- `rd /s %AppData%\npm\`
- `choco install nodejs`
- `npm install -g npm@latest`
- `npm install -g node-gyp@latest`
- `npm install -g typescript@latest`

I was still getting the `missing node-gyp.js` error. What did help was **to properly set `npm config set node_gyp` to point to the correct `node-gyp.js`**, as [suggested here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1663#issuecomment-527104338). Yet somehow the script from that thread didn't work properly for me (as well some other PowerShell/Batch scripts I tried).

**Eventually, I've come up with the following PowerShell 6 one-liner that did the trick for me**:

```
pwsh -Command npm config set node_gyp "`u{22}$(Join-Path $(npm root -g) -ChildPath 'node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js')`u{22}"
```

Hope this helps others and future-me. I'd still recommend going through the above bullet list for clean troubleshooting.